# Trouble identifying a variable type with map overlays

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement the code from this really nice [blog](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-%E2%80%93-part-2-draw-the-route/). I'm down to the last few lines, but I can't figure out what type of variable locationOverlays is. Is there anybody with Google maps Android experience who can figure out what type this is? I've been staring at it for a long time, but I'm not getting anywhere. Thank you.

```
public class RouteActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
drawUserPosition(location);

}

private void drawUserPosition(Location location) {
   GeoPoint currentLocation;
   currentLocation = new GeoPoint((int) ( location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) ( location
   getLongitude() * 1E6));
   OverlayItem currentLocationOverlay = new OverlayItem(currentLocation, getString(R.string.your_location),
   getString(R.string.current_location));
   mapOverlays.clear();
   if (locationOverlays.size() > 1) {
     // remove the old user position if there is one
     locationOverlays.removeOverlay(1);
   }
   //add new user position
   locationOverlays.addOverlay(currentLocationOverlay, this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.someImage));
   mapOverlays.add(locationOverlays);
   //.
   //.  calculate / set the mapcenter, zoom to span
   //.  see in previous posts
   //.
   RouteThread rt = new RouteThread(currentLocation, synyxGeoPoint, routeHandler);
   rt.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to follow blog which uses deprecated Maps API v1. You will not get any good results even if you finish.

Instead switch to using [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). If you want to follow some blog, search for something dated 2013 or later.